# Need Help on Using textwatcher using Strings

Tags: javascript, android

I was wondering if its possible for a String to be randomized? Not sure whats the exact term or word is but here's an example. i have a String called `final String FUNCTION = "</html>";` inside textwatcher, what i want is anything that the user enters on the EditText as long as it inside inside  `final String FUNCTION = "here "` or anything that is inside between `final String function =  "< button p style > "` it will change the color of the inputted text. 
Here's the full Code

```
          txtEditor.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            final String FUNCTION = "</html>";

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                int index = s.toString().indexOf(FUNCTION);
                if (index >= 0) {
                    s.setSpan(
                            new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE),
                            index,
                            index + FUNCTION.length(),
                            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you give a little more clarity? Is FUNCTION supposed to be a user input e.g. text that the user wants highlighted? And the text being watched is another input?

Comment: For example. The User typed the word "</html>" inside the edittext, then that word is going to be highlighted or the color of the text will change.